# What is the way to pass a custom made struct (vector of pointers) from C++ to python using pybind11?

Tags: c++, struct, stdvector, pybind11

For a project, I need to pass a C++ struct to python as an input.
I am not a lot familiar with C++, so I find hard to understand how to do it.
The error I get is:

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type pybind11::cast_error: Unable to convert call argument 'variable' of type 'Example' to Python object

Since I am obviously not telling python how to transform the struct exactly.

I would highly appreciate any hints or feedbacks on how to do it.
Thank you :)

```
//example.cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <memory>


// USE TO COMPILE: g++ -fPIC `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` -undefined dynamic_lookup -std=c++11 -O2 example.cpp -o example -L/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/ `python3-config --libs`

using namespace std;
namespace py = pybind11;
using namespace py::literals; // to bring in the `_a` literal

int MAX_LEN=10;
typedef double Real;

struct Example
{
  Example()
  {
    vector1.reserve(MAX_LEN);
    vector2.reserve(MAX_LEN);
  }
  std::vector<std::vector<Real>> vector1;
  std::vector<std::vector<Real>> vector2;
  ~Example() { clear(); }
  void clear()
  {
    vector1.clear();
    vector2.clear();
  }

};

PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE(exampleModule, m){
    py::class_<Example>(m, "Example")
    .def(py::init<>());
}


int main(void){
  py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
    py::dict locals;

  Example ex;
  ex.vector1 = std::vector <vector<Real>> (MAX_LEN, vector<Real>(MAX_LEN, 1.0));
  ex.vector2 = std::vector <vector<Real>> (MAX_LEN, vector<Real>(MAX_LEN, 2.0));
  locals = py::dict("variable"_a=ex);
  py::exec(R"(

      print(variable)

    )", py::globals(), locals);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nit: your destructor doesn’t do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add binding for the `Example` struct.
This works the same as adding bindings for classes, e.g.:

```
py::class_(m, "Example")
    .def(py::init())
    .def_readwrite("vector1", &Example::vector1)
```

For the STL vector types, remember to include `pybind11/stl.h` also.

More details are available in the [pybind11 documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classes.html#creating-bindings-for-a-custom-type).